# How to short down: list1 show drop1, list2 show drop2, list3 show drop3, etc

Tags: jquery

I have this long fat code, that gets fatter with each new item.

```
$(function () {
  $("#list1").click(function () {
    $(".drop").hide();
    $('#down1').css('display','flex');
  });
  $("#list2").click(function () {
    $(".drop").hide();
    $('#down2').css('display','flex');
  });
  $("#list3").click(function () {
    $(".drop").hide();
    $('#down3').css('display','flex');
  });
  $("#list4").click(function () {
    $(".drop").hide();
    $('#down4').css('display','flex');
  });
  $("#list5").click(function () {
    $(".drop").hide();
    $('#down5').css('display','flex');
  });
  $("#list6").click(function () {
    $(".drop").hide();
    $('#down6').css('display','flex');
  });
});
```

To make into something smaller, I try doing this:

```
$(function() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll("#list");
  var down = document.querySelectorAll("#down");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $("#list[i]").click(function() {
      $(".drop").hide();
      $('#down[i]').css('display', 'flex');
    });
    $("#dowm[i]").click(function() {
      $(".drop").hide();
    });
  };
});
```

The drop class is assigned to each "down" so it hides all the different "down" that are on "show" at the time.

edit2:

this works a little better, but is not the answer i look:

```
$("#list1").click(function(){
$('.listc').not('#down1').removeClass("drop").addClass("hide");
$('#down1').toggleClass("hide drop");
});
$("#list2").click(function(){
$('.listc').not('#down2').removeClass("drop").addClass("hide");
$('#down2').toggleClass("hide drop");
});
$("#list3").click(function(){
$('.listc').not('#down3').removeClass("drop").addClass("hide");
$('#down3').toggleClass("hide drop");
});
$("#list4").click(function(){
$('.listc').not('#down4').removeClass("drop").addClass("hide");
$('#down4').toggleClass("hide drop");
});
$("#list5").click(function(){
$('.listc').not('#down5').removeClass("drop").addClass("hide");
$('#down5').toggleClass("hide drop");
});
$("#list6").click(function(){
$('.listc').not('#down6').removeClass("drop").addClass("hide");
$('#down6').toggleClass("hide drop");
});
```

this is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="menu " id="navigation">
    <a class="home" id="home">Home</a>
    <a class="homicon" id="homicon">&#8962;</a>
 <li>  <a id="list1" class="list" data-drop="drop1">Basics</a>
  <div class="hide listc" id="down1">
    <a id="energies">Energies</a>
    <a id="tools">Tools</a>
    <a id="trigrams">Trigrams</a>
    <a id="recommendations">Recommendations</a>
    <a id="sources">Sources</a>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>  <a id="list2" class="list" data-drop="drop2">Chakras</a>
  <div class="hide listc" id="down2">
    <a id="chakras_intro">Introduction</a>
    <a id="root">Root</a>
    <a id="sacral">Sacral</a>
    <a id="solar">Solar</a>
    <a id="heart">Heart</a>
    <a id="throat">Throat</a>
    <a id="third_eye">Third Eye</a>
    <a id="jade">Jade</a>
    <a id="crown">Crown</a>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li>  <a id="list3" class="list" data-drop="drop3">Elements</a>
  <div class="hide listc" id="down3">
    <a id="elements_intro">Introduction</a>
    <a id="earth">Earth</a>
    <a id="fire">Fire</a>
    <a id="spirit">Spirit</a>
    <a id="water">Water</a>
    <a id="wind">Wind</a>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>  <a id="list4" class="list" data-drop="drop4">Kuji-in</a>
  <div class="hide listc" id="down4">
    <a id="kuji_intro">Introduction</a>
    <a id="rin">Strength</a>
    <a id="pyo">Responsibility</a>
    <a id="to">Harmony</a>
    <a id="sha">Healing</a>
    <a id="kai">Love</a>
    <a id="jin">Listening</a>
    <a id="retsu">Perception</a>
    <a id="zai">Consciousness</a>
    <a id="zen">Enlightenment</a>
    <a id="self-initiation">Self-initiation</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>  <a id="list5" class="list" data-drop="drop5">Meditation</a>
  <div class="hide listc" id="down5">
    <a id="posture">Posture</a>
    <a id="breathing">breathing</a>
    <a id="types">Types</a>
    <a id="energy_storage">Energy Storage</a>
    <a id="empowering">Empowering</a>
    <a id="transmutation">Transmutation</a>
    <a id="harmonizing ">Heaven and Earth</a>
  </div>
</li>
<li>  <a id="list6" class="list" data-drop="drop6">Others</a>
  <div class="hide listc" id="down6">
    <a id="assimilation">Assimilation</a>
    <a id="compassion">Compassion</a>
    <a id="eyesight">Eyesight</a>
    <a id="gate">Gate</a>
    <a id="knowledge">Knowledge</a>
    <a id="regeneration">Regeneration</a>
    <a id="peace">Peace</a>
    <a id="solfeggio">Solfeggio</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class, say `list` for all and do this:

```
$(".list").click(function(){
  $(".drop").hide();
  $('#down' + this.id.substr(-1)).css('display','flex');
});
```

This is the most absurd way of doing it. But the right way is to use the `data-*` attributes and link both the down and list.

Change your current:

```
<div id="list1">
```

To:

```
<div id="list1" class="list">
```

Along with the `data-*` attributes:

```
<div id="list1" class="list" data-drop="drop1">
```

And use in the JavaScript like this:

```
$(".list").click(function(){
  $(".drop").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).data("drop")).css('display','flex');
});
```

---

Also, are you repeating `id` values?

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#list");
```

The above should technically come up with only one single element with a unique ID. Giving the same `id` for multiple elements in HTML is a crime.

Comment: and this code `$(".list").click(function(){
  $(".drop").hide();
  $('#down' + this.id.substr(-1)).css('display','flex');`
}); i do not really uderstand how or where to use? i just paste it onto the script? did nothing.

Comment: i did the `<div id="list1" class="list" data-drop="drop1">` and placed the script code `$(".list").click(function(){ $(".drop").hide(); $("#" + $(this).data("drop")).css('display','flex'); });` as you say and is not working.

Comment: That is pretty much, it will only be missing the CSS and the HTML, that is what you want?